# WPF: Binding the height of a component to another's

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, height

I have, in a window, a `Grid` that contains a `RadioButton`, a `TextBox` and a `Button`, each in column 0, 1, 2, respectively. They all have their heights set to auto.

Then, in another part of the window, I have another `Grid` with a `Label`, a `TextBox` and a `Button`, in columns 0, 1, and 2. Heights are also set to auto.

The problem I have is that the first grid's height is smaller than the second's. I guess it's because Label is forcing the second one to be taller. How can I make it so that the first grid is as tall as the second? I tried doing this:

Name the textbox in the second grid SomeName.
In the `<Grid.ColumnDeclarations>` of the first Grid, I changed Height from "auto" to "{Binding ElementName=SomeName, Path=Height}".

But that didn't do what I wanted. The size was the same. I guess the Binding is basically getting "auto" and throwing it there, which ends up being the same thing.

Also, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve setting the heights to a fixed value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the two grids in a [shared size scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx), and use `SharedSizeGroup` to lock the row heights together:

```
<SomeContainer Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">  <!-- Could be the Window or some more nearby Panel -->
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelAndRadioButtonGroup" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LabelAndRadioButtonGroup" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Grid.Row="0" />
  </Grid>
</SomeContainer>
```

See also [How to: Share sizing properties between grids](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751905.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: How is it possible by using RenderSize.Height ?

Answer (score 55):

Bind to the `ActualHeight` rather than the `Height` property:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=otherTextBox}" />
```

Comment: That didn't work either. The only way I got it to work was adding a label and hiding it. Argh.

Comment: Curious.  I did test it before posting, albeit with a TextBlock rather than a TextBox.  Maybe an issue with margins added by the grid (I wanted to bind to the ActualHeight of the other RowDefinition to avoid this issue, but that didn't work).

Comment: I believe this should be `<RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=otherTextBox}" />`

Comment: awesome stuff , is there is a way to do `element 1 height = < element 2  Height + element 3  Height` > ?