# ListView DataTemplate Grid bind Image height to other View's height

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `ListView` with such a `Grid` `DataTemplate` definiotion:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Tb" Text="{x:Bind Address}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Image Source="{x:Bind SignalResource}" Height="{Binding ElementName=Tb, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
</Grid>
```

I want `Image` take the `TextBlock's` height, but my Binding does not work (as I understood - because when binding is resolved, `ActualHeight` of View is still 0)

The question is how to bind `Image` height to `TextBlock` height?

Comment: Does this question solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232675/wpf-binding-the-height-of-a-component-to-anothers ?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy, no unfortunately (if I understood it correctly). I placed WPF tag in question by accident. I am developping UWP app, and SharedSizeGroup is not available there (still not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ActualHeight* (*Width*) doesn't work as a regular property - [MSDN information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx):

> **Note**  Although it has an ActualHeightProperty backing field, ActualHeight does not raise property change notifications and it should be thought of as a regular CLR property and not a dependency property.

In your case you can use *SizeChanged* event on your *TextBlock* and then adjust the height of the Image. I'm not sure but maybe it will be possible to do it also via *RelativePanel* with proper aligning. Here is a try with *RelativePanel* (as I've tried there is a chance it will work):

```xml
<RelativePanel>
    <TextBlock Name="MyTB" Text="Something" FontSize="24"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="40" RelativePanel.RightOf="MyTB" RelativePanel.AlignTopWith="MyTB" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWith="MyTB"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: I used your answer as a part of weird and complicated solution, and it worked in conclusion